# Selecting char ' (single quote)

Tags: sql

I'm creating a SQL query string in android code which goes as follow:

```
SELECT strftime('%m', DATE) "MONTH", strftime('%Y', DATE) "YEAR" FROM EXPENSES group by month, year ORDER BY MONTH DESC, YEAR DESC
```

I know that if I want to get `"` I write just `'` inside a string,
but what if I want to get that single char `'`?

Could anybody properly enclose this query in quotes, so it works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems a bit confused as to what you need to escape and when.  This should cover it:

- To escape a single quote in SQL, you just double it up.

  ```
  'an escaped single quote '' like that'
  ```
- In Java, you just use double quotes around the outside.

  ```
  "a single quote ' like that"
  ```
- To escape the double quotes in Java, use a leading slash `\` as so:

  ```
  "SELECT strftime('%m', DATE) \"MONTH\", strftime('%Y', DATE) \"YEAR\" FROM EXPENSES group by month, year ORDER BY MONTH DESC, YEAR DESC"
  ```

Comment: thanks, thats exactly what i was looking for. Hovewer I thought that in java ' turns into "